# Why is it possible to call python's datetime.datetime without using ( )?

Tags: python, datetime, call, brackets

I am wondering why this works

```
import datetime as dt

test1 = dt.datetime
print(test)

''' prints: <class 'datetime.datetime'>'''
```

So as far as I understand python, to create an instance of a class you need to call it with brackets like this:

```
test2 = dt.datetime(2021, 12, 31)
```

(Calling the constructor method forces you to put in year, month and day).

At first I thought calling datetime like in the first example (without the brackets) must be an attribute or something. But I can't find a single standing attribute "datetime" in the class "datetime".

And the funny thing is - it doesn't matter how you call it, because both lines lead to the same result:

```
test = dt.datetime
test2 = dt.datetime(2021, 12, 31)

print(test.now())
print(test2.now())
```

But why? What did I miss?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `dt.datetime` is the class `datetime`, not an instance of it.

Comment: `dt.datetime` _is_ `datetime.datetime`, because you did `import datetime as dt`. Here the `dt` refers to the module `datetime`.

Comment: In this first case you are just printing the class identifier itself, not a method from within the class

Comment: You can run `dt.datetime.now()` or call `now()` on an instance of `dt.datetime` because instances can access class methods

Comment: So, short answer: You're _not_ calling it at all (when you call a class, you get returned an instance; when you don't call it, you still have a reference to the class itself). This question in based on a false premise.

Comment: If you're familiar with opening files, does it surprise you that you can do `print(open)`? You didn't give the function any file to open, but it still prints something! It's not called at all, you're just printing the `__repr__` of the method

Comment: Compare to `import datetime as dt; print(dt.datetime)`.

Comment: So that means: dt.datetime is a reference to datetime class, but NOT an instance of it.
When calling test.now() it is actually the same as datetime.datetime,now() - which is actually a class method. And this class method will (somehow) create an instance of datetime in the background and give it back to the caller.
Correct?

Comment: @CodeCannibal as per my answer (which you may or may not have seen), this is not correct. A class method used from the class object (i.e. not an instance) does not create an instance in the background. See references in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to unpack here.

```
import datetime as dt
```

This imports the datetime *module* and aliases it as `dt`. Next, `dt.datetime` is the class `datetime` inside the module `dt` (alias for `datetime` module). Finally, `now()` is defined as a class method so it does not need to be instantiated. Therefore, `dt.datetime.now()` calls the class method `now` of class `datetime` of module `dt` whereas the following:

```
date = dt.datetime(2021, 1, 1)
date.now()
```

Creates an instance of the `datetime` class and then have it access the class method `now`.

See the definition the `datetime` class within the module:

```
# Excerpt of datetime.py on Python 3.8.10
class datetime(date):
    @classmethod
    def now(cls, tz=None):
        "Construct a datetime from time.time() and optional time zone info."
        t = _time.time()
        return cls.fromtimestamp(t, tz)
```

Finally, see here what the [Python reference has to say on the `classmethod` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod):

> A class method can be called either on the class (such as `C.f()`) or on
> an instance (such as `C().f()`). The instance is ignored except for its
> class.

Comment: Thanks a lot - that helped me :-)
As Charles Duffy wrote: "This question in based on a false premise." . I was too focused on finding an class attribute "datetime" within the class "datetime", that I totally overlooked the fact, that "dt.datetime" is a reference to the class itself and not to an instance.
Once again - thank you all for your quick and nice support !